# SharePoint editing for Web test, change pages properties using Visual Studio Test Suite

Tags: sharepoint, automated-tests, webtest, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (SP1) to create a web test that will allow me to edit a page using  `EditForm.aspx`.

I am trying it using fiddler and the recorder. I have managed to get some tests to run, but they do not change the properties.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem. It's probably related to the __REQUESTDIGEST (another mystic sharepoint hidden field) wich must be extracted from the previous request and used in your update request as FORM parameter. Anyway, I didn't manage to make it work. There are prolly some other fields to extract and repost.